# Material Recommendation for Undergraduate Probability III Course.

Tags: probability, statistics, book-recommendation

I am currently in my $2^{nd}$ Year($3^{rd}$ Semester) of Undergraduate Statistics Degree. I am having a Probability III Course(The Syllabus is attached below) as a part of my curriculum. I am finding it little difficult to just follow the Lecture Notes provided by the Professor. 
So, It would be really helpful if I can get some suggestions for study materials to follow alongside. It can be Video Lectures, Lecture Notes, Books, etc. I have decent knowledge of Real Analysis, which was a 2 semester course during my $1^{st}$ Year.
And any additional advice or problem solving materials or tips is also appreciated.

[image: Probability III Syllabus]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many topics in advanced probability are actually just measure theory applied to probability spaces, i.e. to measure spaces where the whole space has measure one. Hence, a nice book on measure theory might come in handy. My favorites are:

(1) [Real Analysis: Modern Techniques and Their Applications by G. Folland](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471317160)

(2) [The Elements of Integration and Lebesgue Measure by R. Bartle](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471042226)

Now, for a more probabilistic approach, you can try e.g:

(1) [Probability and Measure by P. Billingsley](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1118122372). I'd say this is a pretty complete and beautiful book, although it is probably better suited to graduate students.

(2) [Probability: Theory and Examples by R. Durret](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521765390). This one is easier to follow but a little brief at some points IMO.

(3) [A Course in Porbability Theory by K. L. Chung](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0121741516).

Comment: Thank You for these suggestions. Can you please also suggest some lectures notes which have more or less all the topics mentioned covered? I took a look at the books you mentioned they are like really big and I don't think I would be able to complete the sections mentioned in my syllabus in time.